# u'rest_framework' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do Authentication using Django Rest Framework but i am not able to login through DRF panel. When I try to get to the login page by specifying

*/api/api-auth/login/*

```
NoReverseMatch at /api/api-auth/login/
u'rest_framework' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api-auth/login/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
u'rest_framework' is not a registered namespace
Exception Location: /home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse, line 547
Python Executable:  /home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/shivani/aubergine_cubii/test_rest_api2/forked_rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 20 Jan 2015 10:52:13 +0000
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^oauth2/', include('oauth2_provider.urls',
                             namespace='oauth2_provider'))
)
```

**api/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns += [
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                           namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

What should I do?

Comment: There might be a problem in your `urls.py`... Can you show how `urlpatterns` is constructed?

Comment: Added the urls.py and api/urls.py in question! @BernhardVallant

Answer (score 12):

The issue is with your namespaces. Specifically, you are using a nested namespace and Django REST framework was not expecting that to be the case.

The tutorial for [logging into the browsable API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#using-routers) recommends the following snippet of code for your API urls

```
# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
# Additionally, we include the login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

So your login urls will be located at `/api-auth/` and have a namespace of `rest_framework`, so the don't interfere with existing url patterns. This tutorial assumes that you are in the root urlconf when you are putting in the patterns, or at least that you are not using extra namespaces. This is because the url `rest_framework:login` is used to generate the login page for the browsable API, **so the namespace must be `rest_framework`**.

In your case, you are registering the urls under `api`, so the view name is actually `api:rest_framework:login`. The error that you are getting

> u'rest_framework' is not a registered namespace

Is because the `rest_framework` namespace is not a root namespace. You can fix this by moving the urlpattern outside of `api/urls.py`, or [overriding the browsable API templates](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/c0fa92e9adce47d8cde2c6dea4b1e30f64f5a92c/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html#L44-L50).

Comment: I can't move urls.py outside of api because I want the authentication on application level and on application level i can't find a way to login. 

How can I register the 'rest_framework' namespace? or Can you provide details on overriding the browsable API template?

Comment: The code and comment in the tutorial that was linked here was edited in a more recent version. Here's the version at the time this answer was posted: http://web.archive.org/web/20150114020613/https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the line `url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework'))`, to your main `urls.py` or change the `namespace` of `api/` to `rest_framework` instead (and remove it from the other url)...

Comment: That's working but i want authentication on API level.

Comment: name space
    rest_framework is already specified on    
    /api/urls.py

Answer (score 2):

In my case I put this line:
`path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),`
inside my app level `urls.py` when you should put it in your project level `urls.py`.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the namespace from api you can simply remove the namespace from your route

```
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api'))
```

I have the same issue and for me works because I don't use the namespace from api nowhere

Answer (score -1):

Put this line in your URL section:

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```